# Why is BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb abstract?

Tags: java, android, oop, design-patterns

Why has `android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb` been declared abstract when it doesn't really have any abstract methods? I understand they don't want anyone to instantiate `BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb`, but why don't they just write the content of the method `onCreate()` of `BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb` inside `FragmentActivity`?

Is this just historical or by chance, or does it have good design intentions?

Comment: Asking "why did Developer X make Decision Y?" on Stack Overflow is rarely useful. The only party who can definitively answer the question is Developer X, and it is unlikely that Developer X will see the question. Anybody else can only offer guesses. Asking "why would you declare a class as `abstract` when it has no `abstract` methods?" is valid, and you could cite this case as an example.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. There are several design choices that are simply sensible and a more experienced developer may look at them and say "well, it's obvious." (Or maybe the developer **has** writen about their decision.) If this isn't the case of this particular question, you should explain why.

Answer (score 1):

> why don't they just write the content of the method onCreate of BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb inside FragmentActivity?

I can only speculate that they are reduce the number of concerns of `FragmentActivity` trying follow the principle of single responsibility in [SOLID programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

Let's look at the code for that `BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    final View v = dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
    if (v == null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        // If we're running on HC or above, let the super have a go
        return super.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
    }
    return v;
}
```

While it might seem trivial to include that as a block inside the `onCreate` of the subclass, the `onCreate()` method of `FragmentActivity` is already 37 lines long. It makes it easier to understand for the maintenance programmer if the specific functionality related to Honeycomb compatibility is in its own isolated class.